# Django: save foreign key according to string parameter?

Tags: django

Here is the thing.
A branch may contains many products.
A form would post `path` and `branch` to product model, in string format.

How could I use like this `Product.objects.create(path="path1", branch="branch1")` when got the posted data?
or the branch instance must be created in forms.py?

Here is the wrong version: it would raise `ValueError: Cannot assign "'branch1'": "Product.branch" must be a "Branch" instance.`

```
class Branch(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=63, unique=True, blank=True)


class Product(models.Model):
    path = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    branch = models.ForeignKey(Branch, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['branch'], _ = Branch.objects.get_or_create(name=kwargs['branch'])
        super(Product, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not the save issue. The error raises during the assignment of string to branch name. If you want to implement the logic, do it before saving

You can use python `property` to achieve this, with small modifications as shown below. Don't need to override `save` method.

models.py

```
class Branch(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=63, unique=True)


class Product(models.Model):
    path = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    branch = models.ForeignKey(Branch, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    @property
    def branch_name(self):
        return self.branch.name
    @branch_name.setter
    def branch_name(self, value):
        self.branch, _ = Branch.objects.get_or_create(name=value)
```

And your create function should be

```
Product.objects.create(path="path1", branch_name="branch1")
```

**NOTE :** It is `branch_name` and not `branch`. Also `product.branch` remains the `branch` object and `poduct.branch_name` returns the name of the branch. This will work with updation also. That is `product.branch_name` to new value updates the `branch` of the `product`

Comment: According to your idea "do it before saving", I overrided model manager's create method， in which the parameters were successfully replaced. Thank you.

Comment: model manager overriding is not a flexible solution. You will make it impossible to get or update the branch object from the product object